# What does '=>' mean (in functions / property context)?

Tags: c#, function, lambda, operators, expression-body

I got an auto generated code using Lambdas while developing a Xamarin application:

```
public override string this[int position] => throw new NotImplementedException();

public override int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

What does the **`=>` operator** mean in this context?

Thanks
R

Comment: Google "c# lambda expression"

Comment: These aren't lambda expressions. The question title is misleading. Re-opening, as answers detailing what lambda expressions are aren't useful here. These are [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Comment: Sorry about the title, could you explain what those two statements do please

Comment: Thumbs up for reopening this. I remember seeing these for the first time and until today it is still very hard to google for "=>". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not lambdas, they are [Expression-bodied Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)!

In the context of a property, these are basically the getters of a property simplified to become a single expression (as opposed to a whole statement).

This:

```
public override int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public override int Count {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @sweeper says in your example they do not relate to lambda expressions as they are expression body operators (which were introduced in C# 6 and expanded on in 7). It is also used to indicate a lambda expression though, so it's usage is two fold.

Further information on each usage of the `=>` operator can be found here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify that the `=>`operator is currently used in two different contexts:

1. Lambda expressions. 
   Often you will see them in Linq, e.g. 
   `var query = Customers.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName);`
2. Expression bodied functions. This is what we have here.

In order to understand what **`=>`** means, please take a look at the following simple example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Test();
        obj.Count.Dump();
        obj[7].Dump();
    }


    class Test
    {
        public int Count => 1;
        public string this[int position] => $"2 x {position} = {(2*position)}";
    }
}
```

> Dumping object(Int32)
>    1
>   Dumping object(String)
>    2 x 7 = 14

[Try it in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6EY9C)

Here, the `NotImplementedException` code, which is just there to tell you (the developer) that the property and indexer is not implemented but should be, is replaced by some function:

- Count is a readonly property returning always 1
- whenever you apply `[ ... ]` to the object, the doubled index is returned

**Note** that in earlier versions of C# you had to write:

```
class Test
{
        public int Count { get { return 1; } }
        public string this[int position] { 
            get { return String.Format("2 x {0} = {1}", 
                                       position, (2*position).ToString()); }}
}
```

which is equivalent to the code above. So in essence in C#7 you have to type much less to achieve the same result.